# R error "number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement

Tags: r, rstudio-server

```
pdf_1 <- vector()

for(i in 1:100) {
  x <- runif(100, 0, 5)
  pdf_1[i] <- x
}
```

I'm not sure how to get this too run, I keep getting the same error!

Comment: What do you want to do? you want to fill `pdf_1` with the elements of `x`?

Comment: Please clarify!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure this is what you want but this way you can fill `pdf_1` with values of `x`:

```
pdf_1 <- vector("double", length = 100)

for(i in 1:100) {
  x <- runif(100, 0, 5)
  pdf_1[[i]] <- x[[i]]
}
head(pdf_1)
[1] 4.4140316 2.8390462 2.7328587 0.5423461 0.1792465 2.2133986
```

You need to put an iterator `i` for `x` too.

Comment: Thank you that worked perfectly for what I needed!

Comment: Dear @imconfused Please feel free to upvote or accept any answer that might serve your purpose. Thanks.

Comment: Always remember to create an empty vector of your desired type (here "double") with a pre-defined length. For example here we knew before we run the for loop that the output should be of length 100. However this may not always be the case. But if so it would be much better and enhances the speed of the loop. And also for choosing and assigning a single element always use double bracket `[[` instead of `[`.